# How to remove header name / column name from datatable

Tags: c#

[image]I only want data not header column names from the DataTable result set. or is it possible to create a DataTable without column headers. i tried every possible scenario but couldn't get anything.
above

Is my sp result, which I can very easily convert into DataTable. But I don't want to header row. there is option in SQL where we can include or exclude the column headers but even that is not working

Your help is highly appreciated.

this is my test c# code

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Rmtest1", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@unitName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = unitName;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@startdate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = startDate;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(table);
```

So basically I want the rows but not the headers

Comment: What is exactly your problem?

Comment: What do you mean `DataTable`? The DataTable class has no headers. It's not visible either, it's a data structure. What you posted here looks like a grid control. Which control, for which stack? Winforms, WPF, Webforms, MVC? All of them can be configured to display headers or not

Comment: Your problem is probably not "how do I get my columns to have no names anymore", but "how do I get whatever I'm using to display a data table to not display the column names in a separate row". The problem is that it's not clear what you're using for display! The screenshot you've posted appears to come from Management Studio, and no, you can't make Management Studio leave out the column names. But your question is tagged `c#`, and in C# there are plenty of ways to do things with data tables. But what are you *actually* doing with them? Is there any code?

Comment: yes above is my test c# code

Comment: Well, `DataTable` has separate `Rows` and `Columns` collections (and the `Rows` do *not* contain the column names as a separate row). You can very well process what's in the `Rows` without ever looking at the column names. It's just that all the default visualizations of a table will usually include the column names. `DataTable` doesn't get to decide how it's displayed.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cant hide/remove the column header, but you can change the column header name with some string space (" ") to make the column header looks like blank.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide column header from DataTable. But you can hide it from your displaying control. I'm not sure which control you want to use for your case, but you can use the following code to hide it from DataGridView in WinForm App.

```
dgwStudents.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
```